# Xcode says that I cannot assign type 'Int' to type 'String'. What should I do?

Tags: swift

```
@IBOutlet var highScore: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  highScore.text = mhighScoreNum
}
```

Comment: You should convert the `Int` to a `String`

Comment: `highScore.text = "\(mhighScoreNum)"`

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
  highScore.text = "\(mhighScoreNum)"
```

Though basic!